# AFNetworking GET parameters with JSON (NSDictionary) string contained in URL key parameter

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, afnetworking-2, url-encoding

This JSON string has to be sent:

```
{
"dashboard": "compact",
"theme": "dark",
"show_side_bar": "yes"
}
```

to a REST API using **GET** method in this format (since server retrieves data with this PHP code `$_GET["setting"]`) with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, such that the equivalent URL becomes:

`http://www.examplesite.com/api/change_setting?setting={ "dashboard" : "compact", "theme" : "dark", "show_side_bar" : "yes" }`

When I create an `NSDictionary` of parameters in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`'s `GET:parameters:success:failure:` which adds the **url key parameter** to the parameter dictionary itself like this:

```
{
  "setting": {
    "dashboard": "compact",
    "theme": "dark",
    "show_side_bar": "yes"
  }
}
```

In short **only** the JSON string must be encapsulated in **setting** parameter **NOT** as object of **setting** in a JSON string.

Edit:
Here's the code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             kSettingDashboard: @"compact",
                             kSettingTheme: @"dark",
                             kSettingShowSideBar: @"yes"
                             };

[manager GET:kURLChangeSetting
  parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:parameters forKey:@"setting"]
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         // code
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         /// code
     }];
```

Comment: Why is this not a POST or PUT? Show the code where you create and set the dictionary and JSON

Comment: @Wain since the API uses GET method. Added the code. I don't have any idea how can this be achieved. Some pointers on this will really help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
NSString *parametersString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[manager GET:kURLChangeSetting
  parameters:@{@"setting" : parametersString}
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         // code
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         /// code
     }];
```

Comment: if you know then , please can you explain why it happens  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can ask the php developer to change the `GET` To `request` so that you send data in `POST` so that your data can be sent in large amount and securely also