# AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue not giving proper URL with NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, request, afnetworking

I am trying to send following parameters in GET method call:

```
{
    query =     {
        "$or" =         (
                        {
                name = yes;
            },
                        {
                status = Open;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

But it seems it is not returning the proper URL:
[baseURL/objects?query%5B%24or%5D%5B%5D%5Bname%5D=yes&query%5B%24or%5D%5B%5D%5Bstatus%5D=Open](http://baseURL/objects?query%5B%24or%5D%5B%5D%5Bname%5D=yes&query%5B%24or%5D%5B%5D%5Bstatus%5D=Open)

I was expecting to "Or" my data, but it is doing "And".
I am using `AFURLRequestSerialization` class.

I have followed this SO, but it gives me all the object without applying any query.
 [AFNetworking GET parameters with JSON (NSDictionary) string contained in URL key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177080/afnetworking-get-parameters-with-json-nsdictionary-string-contained-in-url-key)

It was working properly in POST call, but in GET it is not working as expected.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure @halfer. Next time onwards I will keep in mind this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by converting dictionary against *query* key to a string and adding this string as a value of key *query* in the dictionary.
 So my parameters will look like:

```
parameters: {
    query = "{\"$or\":[{\"name\":\"yes\"},{\"status\":\"Open\"}]}";
}
```

Then I am passing this dictionary to AFNetworking.